# What's the point of using namespace inside include? (Django 2.0)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

What's the point of using namespace inside include, if adding app_name in the app's urls is the one that actually lets me use the "app:view" syntax.

### Blog_app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
    from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
    from . import views

    app_name = 'posts'  #APP_NAME

    urlpatterns = [
           path('',RedirectView.as_view(url='posts/'), name='home'),
           path('posts/',views.post_list, name='list'),
           path('posts/detail/<int:pk>',views.post_detail, name='detail'),
           path('posts/delete',views.post_delete, name='delete'),
           path('posts/create',views.post_create, name='create'),
           path('posts/update',views.post_update, name='update'),]
```

### Project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog_app.urls',namespace='posts')),]
```

this code works for reversing the url to posts/detail like this

### example.html

```
<a href="{% url 'posts:list' %}"> Example <a/>
```

but if delete the namespace it stills reverses my url to posts/detail

### Project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog_app.urls')), #NAMESPACE DELETED

]
```

Comment: Because you can have multiple instances of a single app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app name `app_name = 'posts'` in the **Blog_app/urls.py** works as a url namespace. if you delete it, you will get a namespace error. You can assign another namespace in `include` and both can be used as a url namespace.

Comment: I still dont get it fully. Please tell me if I am right. if I set the namespace inside `include` and not in `app_name` i get an error... so necessarily I have to write `app_name` in order to use a namespace for my app and if I want two namespace I can put another in `include`? Like this: include('app.urls',namespace='app1') and app_name = 'app2' the I can either choose {% url 'app1:view'  %} or {% url app2:view %} ? Its that what you meant?

Comment: you are right. you have always to assign the app_name, and then you can assign another namespace in the include, then you can use either name in the template. removing app_name will cause this error  Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

As Django website said:

> URL namespaces allow you to uniquely reverse named URL patterns even
>   if different applications use the same URL names. It’s a good practice
>   for third-party apps to always use namespaced URLs (as we did in the
>   tutorial). Similarly, it also allows you to reverse URLs if multiple
>   instances of an application are deployed. In other words, since
>   multiple instances of a single application will share named URLs,
>   namespaces provide a way to tell these named URLs apart.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces